# How to access a value fetched from a JsonStore with ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the following JS code, I am trying to read json data from url:

```
// Create JsonStore
var storeED = new Ext.data.JsonStore({                    
            url: './wfServlet?workd=' + workd
                + '&type=detail' + '&status=' + status +'&userName='+userName,
            root: 'root',
            fields: [{name:'ERROR_DESC'}]
            });
```

then I want to get the value from the field `ERROR_DESC`.

```
Ext.getCmp('errorMessage').setValue(storeED.ERROR_DESC);// want  to read value
```

The code just above doesn't work for me.
 What am I missing ?

Comment: there could be multiple records in the store, then which value do you want to fetch

Comment: Did you check what you respond was?

Comment: also extjs version used

Comment: You get the first `ERROR_DESC` using `storeED.get(0).get('ERROR_DESC')` it could throw an error in the store is empty

Answer (score 2):

Stores don't have values. Stores are caches of `Ext.data.Model` instances, which are what hold values which are mapped to the fields defined for the Model which is applied to the Store.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll need to access the instance of the Model inside your store which contains the record data you desire, such as `storeEd.getAt(0)`, assuming you only have one model instance in your store's cache.

If this is the only field AND you only expect one instance to live within this store, it might be better to not even bother with a store at all. You could either add a proxy to the Model itself, or just use the value returned from a regular `Ext.Ajax.request`. If you don't plan on using this value beyond this particular usage, a store is probably unnecessary.